How to pass route params from a parent navigator to a nested navigator react native
I have a bottom navigator that has a route that routes a nested stack navigator.
when I do
    navigator.navigate("parentNavigator", {id: id})

It gets route.params as undefined in the default component of parent component. I am thinking in changing my app style only because of this limitation. Here is my code
I have this styled button
    import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import React from 'react';
    import { View, Text, Pressable, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';
    
    interface ServiceTileProps {
      categoryName?: string; 
      foto?: any// Assuming categoryName is a string, adjust the type accordingly
      id?: number
    }
    
    const ServiceTile: React.FC<ServiceTileProps> = ({ id, categoryName, foto }) => {
    
      const navigation = useNavigation(); // Obtenha o objeto de navegação
    
      console.log("id")
      console.log(categoryName)
    
      return (
    
        <View style={style.tileItem}>
    
          <Pressable onPress={() => { console.log("logar clique"); navigation.navigate('procurar', { id: id, servicoProcurado: categoryName }) }} android_ripple={{ color: "#ccc" }} style={style.pressableButton}>
    
            <Text style={style.label}>{categoryName}</Text>
            <View style={style.innerContainer}>
    
              <Image style={style.image} source={foto} />
    
            </View>
          </Pressable>
        </View >
      );
    }
    
    export default ServiceTile;

Like the code does, it routes to the parent navigator
This goes to the procurar route
     onPress={() => { console.log("logar clique"); navigation.navigate('procurar', { id: id, servicoProcurado: categoryName }) }}

This is my App.tsx
         import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
    import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
    import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
    import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
    
    import Main from './screens/Main'
    import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
    import Profile from './screens/Profile';
    import LoginOptions from './screens/LoginOptions';
    import LoginTelefone from './screens/LoginTelefone';
    import ProfileMenu from './screens/ProfileMenu';
    import SearchServices from './screens/SearchServices';
    import WorkOrders from './screens/WorkOrders';
    import UserInformationContextProvider from './store/context/state';
    import DetalhesPrestador from './screens/DetalhesPrestador';
    
    const bottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator()
    const stackNavigator = createNativeStackNavigator()
    
    function StackNavigator() {
      return <stackNavigator.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          contentStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' }
        }}
        initialRouteName='listaPrestadores'
      >
    
        <stackNavigator.Screen 
         options={{
          title: 'Busca de Serviços'
    
        }}
          
        name="listaPrestadores"  component={SearchServices}>
        </stackNavigator.Screen>

        <stackNavigator.Screen 
         options={{
          title: 'Prestador do Serviço'
        }}
    
        name="detalhesPrestador"  component={DetalhesPrestador}>
    
        </stackNavigator.Screen>
    
      </stackNavigator.Navigator >;
    }
    Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
      handleNotification: async () => {
        return {
          shouldPlaySound: false,
          shouldSetBadge: false,
          shouldShowAlert: true
        };
      }
    });
    
    
    export default function App() {
    
      scheduleNotificationHandler()
    
      async function scheduleNotificationHandler() {
        try {
          const notificationId = await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
            content: {
              title: 'A tomada não funciona, a casa anda uma bagunça...',
              body: 'Pró serviços - o serviço que você procura.'
            },
            trigger: {
              seconds: 1
            }
          });
          console.log(`Notification scheduled with id: ${notificationId}`);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error scheduling notification:', error);
        }
      }
    
      return (
        <UserInformationContextProvider>
    
    
          <NavigationContainer
    
          >
            <bottomTabNavigator.Navigator
    
              screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
                tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: 'white' }
              }}
    
            >
    
              <bottomTabNavigator.Screen
                options={{
                  tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                    <Ionicons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
                  )
                }}
                name="serviços comuns" component={Main}   >
    
              </bottomTabNavigator.Screen>
    
    
              <bottomTabNavigator.Screen
    
                options={{
                  tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                    <Ionicons name="search" color={color} size={size} />
                  )
                }}
    
                name="procurar"  component={StackNavigator}>
    
              </bottomTabNavigator.Screen>
    
            </bottomTabNavigator.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </UserInformationContextProvider>
      );
    }

When I access searchServices component, it is undefined
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
    import { NavigationProp, ParamListBase, useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { getPrestadoresServicos } from '../utils/http';
    import SearchResult from '../components/SearchResult';
    import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';
    
    interface ProfileMenuProps {
      navigation: NavigationProp<ParamListBase>;
    }
    
    const SearchServices: React.FC<ProfileMenuProps> = ({ navigation }) => {
    
    
    
    
      const [prestadoresServicos, setPrestadoresServicos] = useState<any[]>([]);
      const [resultado, setResultado] = useState([]);
      const [servicoProcurado, setServicoProcurado] = useState<string>('');
      const [selectedLabel, setSelectedLabel] = useState<string>('');
    
      const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("6");
    
      const handleChange = (value: string, label: string) => {
        setSelectedValue(value);
       
       
      };
    
    
    
      const options = [
        { label: 'Segurança Residencial', value: "5" },
        { label: 'Elétrica', value: "6" },
        { label: 'Internet e Redes', value: "7" },
        { label: 'Televisão', value: "8" },
        { label: 'Telefonia', value: "9" },
        { label: 'Limpeza Doméstica', value: "10" },
        { label: 'Instalação de Equipamentos', value: "11" },
        { label: 'Instalação de Câmeras', value: "12" },
      ];
      const route = useRoute();
    
      
      console.log("parajhjjms")
      console.log(route)
    
    
      useEffect(() => {
    
        const fetchPrestadores = async (id: string) => {
          const resultado = await getPrestadoresServicos(id);
          setPrestadoresServicos(resultado);
          
          
        };
    
      
    
        if (route.params !== undefined) {
          const { id, servicoProcurado } = route.params; // undefined
          alert(id)
          fetchPrestadores(id);
    
       
        }
       
    
      
    
      }, [selectedValue]);
    
      const popularResultados = async (idServiçoSelecionado: string) => {
        
          const resultado = await getPrestadoresServicos(idServiçoSelecionado);
          setResultado(resultado);
          
          const selectedOption = options.find(option => option.value === idServiçoSelecionado);
        if (selectedOption) {
          setSelectedLabel(selectedOption.label);
        }
         
    
      };
    
      return (
        <View>
        <View>
              <Text>Tipo de Serviço Procurado</Text>
              <View>
              <RNPickerSelect
     onValueChange={(value, label) => handleChange(value, label)}      items={
         
    options
          }
          value={selectedValue}
        />
              </View>
              <View>
                <Button title="buscar" onPress={() => {popularResultados(selectedValue)}} />
              </View>
              <View>
                <Text>resultado para: {selectedLabel}</Text>
              </View>
              <View>
                {resultado.map((item, index) => (
                  <SearchResult  id={item.id} foto={item.foto} primeiroNome={item.primeiroNome} whatsapp={item.celular} descricao={item.descricao} ></SearchResult>
                ))}
              </View>
              {resultado.length === 0 && (
              
              <View style={styles.containerSemResultado}>
                <Text style={styles.semResultado}>Nenhum resultado encontrado</Text>
                  <View>
                  <Text style={styles.semResultado2}>Estamos trabalhando para conseguir mais prestadores na sua região.</Text>
                    </View>
              </View>)}
               
            </View>
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    export default SearchServices;

here is undefined
       const { id, servicoProcurado } = route.params; // undefined



I did I will post my answer, it is a specialized way of calling navigate.

On your SearchServices component, get the navigation from a hook, instead of from a prop.
Something like the following code (it's just a snippet, not supposed to be feature complete):
import {useNavigation} from "@react-navigation/native";

const SearchServices: React.FC<ProfileMenuProps> = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (...);
};

